# prettyfaces not supported for JRE 6

Tags: java, jsf, java-6, prettyfaces

My client is using java 6 for deploy their applications, is it any other way to support java 6? What version of pretty faces that support java 6? And what changes I had to make to the configuration if I downgrade to that version?

Error on deploying war shown below :

```
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive orlansoft-service.war
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/ocpsoft/rewrite/servlet/impl/RewriteServletRequestListener : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.RewriteServletRequestListener)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2822)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadClassAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:145)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:73)
  a
```

Comment: Tell your client to upgrade 3 years ago, perhaps.  There's really not much you can do if this third-party JAR refuses to support an out-of-date JRE.

Comment: if its simple as that to ask the client to update their application :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 6 support has been dropped in this commit:

https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/commit/92f6178730f6456eac37a1d975be3faa2c348b5c

So you could either use any version released before that (like `3.0.0.Alpha7`) or convince your client to use a more modern Java version. :-)